# pyrocms codeigniter widgets modules

Tags: codeigniter, pyrocms

My question is do widgets get in on any custom libraries that I add to a custom module? What I want to achieve is create a custom module and I want to add ability to generate pdf documents so I was thinking of making the pdf generation a widget as I would like to use that on another site. If I made it a module, would I be able to share the resources between my pdfmodule and any other module? Sometimes I wish there was a book written on pyrocms that clarifies these issues.

Comment: A `module` is the most appropriate to build a complex addon. But please explain a little more: What resources to share do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it took a month to spot this one, but we generally help out on the support forums and don't look here as often.

SO, cross loading resources. Yep that is supported just fine. We use the HMVC plugin for CodeIgniter and often forget that people don't know too much about how it works. I'll get something added to the documentation for this, but basically you just specify the module name like this:

```
$this->load->library('modulename/libraryname');
```

Hope this helps anyone finding this in the future. It's probably a bit late for Eagletrophy.